# Can I use Laravel Sail to setup a Laravel 7 + PHP 7 environment?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sail

We have a legacy application written for Laravel 7 and PHP 7.

I have a LinuxMint 20 (basically an Ubuntu 20) and PHP 8 (as default PHP) as development machine.

Tried to setup a development environment made out of Laravel 7 and PHP 7 with Sail but failed. It seems that Sail requires a minimum Laravel 8.

If I change the (docker-compose.yml's) runtime to 7.4 the moment the docker container is up the composer's call inside that container will fail due to the fact that Sail dependency need PHP 8. So any path I took I was blocked.

To sum it up here is the question: **Can I use Sail to setup a Laravel 7 + PHP 7 environment?**

Comment: Probably not. Sail didn't exist for Laravel 7. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-sail-for-older-laravel-versions

Comment: Well...if you install Sail you will see that there is a whole runtime dedicated to 7.4 (ex: check "/vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/7.4"). So why supporting PHP 7.4 ? Only to allow Laravel 8 with Sail?

Comment: Laravel 8 has a minimum requirement of PHP 7.3, which is why PHP 7.4 is supported.